# Fire SelectedIndexChanged event on button click for dropdown

Tags: c#, dropdownbox

i change dropdown list with button click like this:

```
ddl.selectedIndex+=1
```

my ddl has a SelectedIndexChanged event which is not firing if index changed through button. Is it a normal behavior? Should I create separate method and call it right after the `ddl.selectedIndex+=1` or there's a better way?

Comment: You might want to specify the type of dropdown list and technology you use. Do you mean ASP ListControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using ASP.NET? If so, setting `AutoPostBack` may help:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
```